# Syntax for empty dictionary in YAML

Tags: yaml

How do I denote an empty dictionary in YAML? I.e. it should be semantically equivalent to the empty json-object `{}`.

Comment: If you are familiar with JSON, I would suggest you to use this https://www.json2yaml.com/ converter. You can get equivalent Yaml for any JSON.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

Short answer: use `{}`

There are two ways to denote mappings (dictionaries) in yaml; [flow mappings](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2790832) and [block mappings](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2798057):

```
block_mapping:
    name:  foo
    id:    bar
flow_mapping: { name: foo, id: bar }
empty_flow_mapping: {}
```

The flow mapping style is thus suitable for representing empty mappings.

Comment: empty list would be []

Comment: Why is it unsuitable though? What's wrong with just "empty_block_mapping:" (and nothing following that)

Comment: @JonathanHartley just leaving the right-hand-side of `empty_block_mapping:` blank is the equivalent of `empty_block_mapping: null`, not `empty_block_mapping: {}`.

Answer (score 12):

General technique for answering this type of question, to supplement Betamos’s correct answer: use irb.

```
$ irb
2.2.0 :001 > require 'yaml'
 => true 
2.2.0 :002 > puts({}.to_yaml)   # original question
--- {}
 => nil 
2.2.0 :003 > puts({ mixed_types: [{}, "string", :symbol, {symbol: "value"}, nil, 3] }.to_yaml)
---
:mixed_types:
- {}
- string
- :symbol
- :symbol: value
- 
- 3
 => nil
```

I use this whenever I’m unsure how to encode something.

Comment: `irb` is the REPL for Ruby, for those who don't recognize it.