# How to make a Django fixture for a model with no fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, yaml, django-fixtures

If I have a Django model, with some field(s) defined:

```
# model.py

from django.db import models


class Model(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I can initialize it by using a fixture:

```
# sample.yaml

- model: app.Model
  pk: 1
  fields:
    text: "some text"
```

with the command: `manage.py loaddata sample.yaml` and everything works fine.

**My problem is that I cannot do the same for a model with no fields**:

```
# model.py

from django.db import models


class Model(models.Model):
    pass
```

```
# sample.yaml

- model: app.Model
  pk: 1
  fields:
```

Then the same `manage.py loaddata sample.yaml` command gives an error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 73, in Deserializer
>    yield from PythonDeserializer(yaml.load(stream, Loader=SafeLoader), **options)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 112, in Deserializer
>    for (field_name, field_value) in d["fields"].items():
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
>        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>        utility.execute()
>      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
>        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
>        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
>        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
>        self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
>      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
>        self.load_label(fixture_label)
>      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 172, in load_label
>        for obj in objects:
>      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 77, in Deserializer
>        raise DeserializationError() from exc
>    django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/app/src/app/fixtures/sample.yaml':
> ```

I also tried without specifying `fields` at all:

```
# sample.yaml

- model: app.Model
  pk: 1
```

and I get a similar but different error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 73, in Deserializer
>    yield from PythonDeserializer(yaml.load(stream, Loader=SafeLoader), **options)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 112, in Deserializer
>    for (field_name, field_value) in d["fields"].items():
> KeyError: 'fields'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
>    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>    utility.execute()
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
>    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
>    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
>    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
>    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
>    self.load_label(fixture_label)
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 172, in load_label
>    for obj in objects:
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/pyyaml.py", line 77, in Deserializer
>    raise DeserializationError() from exc
> django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/app/src/app/fixtures/sample.yaml':
> ```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Fixtures are meant to provide initial data for a model. A fixture for a model with no fields doesn't do anything.

Comment: @bdoubleu It will allow me have a foreign key reference to it from an other model. I understand that this might be a bad design decision, but I was simply wondering how this could be achieved.

Comment: It might not be a bad design decision. I have a base model (with some fields) and some descendant models that extend that model. Some of them have no fields yet and will get some in a later point of time. So they are basically models with no fields themselves. But they can queried in the database as different models as the base class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YAML works pretty much the same way as JSON does, so we can simply specify `fields` to be an [empty dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510095/9835872):

```
# sample.yaml

- model: app.Model
  pk: 1
  fields: {}
```

Comment: Exactly!! The parser looks for the `items` attribute, only a dict has.

Answer (score 1):

It works using a JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "model": "app.Model",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {}
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with `yaml`?